# How to make to ultrasonic sensor start a webcamera?

Tags: processing

How to amend a code in processing to start a webcamera (laptop camera) and detect a face. I couldn't figure it out. I was trying to find solution on youtube and instructables but without any luck.

Here is a tutorial I'm using:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultrasonic-sensor-detects-someone-in-front-of-your/

I will be greatfull for help. I'm a total beginner so please remember about it :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too broad for StackOverflow. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to answer in a general sense.

**You need to break your problem down into smaller steps.**

**Step 1:** Can you create a small example program that prints something out when an ultrasonic sensor is triggered?

**Step 2:** Can you create a **separate** small example program that connects to a camera?

**Step 3:** Can you create a small example program that connects to a camera after the user clicks the mouse?

**Step 4:** Can you create a small example program that detects a face?

Focus on one small step at a time, and don't even think about combining them until you have every small example program working perfectly by itself. Then when you get stuck, you can post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question, and we can go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thank you for your help. I have hound this code for camera in processing: https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/LiveCamTest/LiveCamTest.pde  It works well. I guess I need now some ‘if’ statement in processing to start camera when ultrasonic sensor is activated. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @ChrisW You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve] and a specific technical question in a new post. Try to keep the code as short as possible (while still allowing us to copy-paste to get the same results) and the question as specific as possible. "How do I do this?" isn't very specific, and the answer is "break it down into even smaller pieces." Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your time. I did it today finally. It wasn't easy. All the best

Comment: @ChrisW No problem. If this answer helped, you might consider throwing it an upvote or accepting it. Happy coding!